# Вылетает Visual Studio 2017 при использовании intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2017, intellisense

При наборе текста "bool" в редакторе в определенном файле *.cpp Visual Studio 2017 вылетает/закрывается принудительно. Выяснил следующее, при отключении функции автоматической подстановки операторов intellisense данного сбоя не происходит (Отключаю следующим образом: Средства - Параметры - Текстовый редактор - Все языки - Убрать галочку "Автоматически отображать список членов". Взято из статьи: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rusaraford/2009/03/09/98-intellisense/).

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно предпринять, чтобы intellisense оставался включенным и не происходило данного сбоя?

Microsoft Visual Studio Profesional 2017
Версия 15.3.3

Comment: Возможно конфликт решарпера и intellisense.

Comment: ReSharper не установлен

Comment: Значит бага в самой версии, у вас стоит старая, уже есть версия выше.

Comment: Для начала следует создать минимальный пример для воспроизведения этой проблемы. Затем отправить баг репорт в MS Connect.